# Finding values in value list by typing part of the value in QField

Tags: qfield, value-list

In QField you have to select a values from drop down value list by scrolling to the desired value. When the value list is very long it would be very helpful if you could enter only a part of the value or only the first letter to select the desired value much faster.

In QGIS you can use the keyboard. Is there a similar option in QField available?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, QField has this function. I am using QField 1.9.1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Kadir Şahbaz, Thank you for your comment. I updated my version to 1.9.1 but I do not see the magnifying glass. Do you know how I activate this? 

Kind regards,  Sebastiaan

Comment: I guess you use Unique values in your project. Try to create a non-spatial layer with values you need and use Value relation widget on layer where you want to use these values.

Comment: Hello BlackTesta, Thank you for your reply. I am not using the Unique Values but a Value map. Perhaps your solution might work but it is still a workaround. So I am just looking for an option to activate the search field when using Value maps like in the example of Kadir Şahbaz. If this is not available I will raise a feature request to have this implemented.